# How to get communities of a SPUser

Tags: 2013

I need to know if there is any way to get from a SPUser the number of communities he is joined, I mean, not using the "What's happening" webpart. I want to build up a page with a Webpart that renders three communities of my choice and the position in the webpart. The three communities should indicate number of members, three last messages in the newsfeed (if appropriate), and number of posts in blog, wikis, document libraries, etc.

Do I need statistics to get this kind of information? Should I use Sharepoint Object model instead?

Here is an example of what I need:

- Community name
- Number of members
- Community activity (messages, docs uploaded to library, etc)
- Number of posts in calendar, blog, wiki that belongs to community

Thank you all!